# using java to manipulate a minecraft server input/output

Tags: java, input, output, minecraft

I'm trying to manage my minecraft server through java but even though i can read outputs easily I can't manage to get commands or even text in:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd C:\\my\\path\\ && java -jar server.jar nogui");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p;

p = builder.start();
this.p = p;

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (loop) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line == null) { break; }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This works just fine but when I try to send commands it doesn't work at all:

```
OutputStream os = BotData.minecraftServer.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
String stop = "stop";
try {
    out.write(stop + "\n");
    out.write("\n");
    out.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tried with `"Command:>>" + stop + "\n"`
with or without `/` before `stop` etc.

Killing the process, forcibly or not, starting it in a  thread I'd then stop...

I can get neither text nor commands to work.

Comment: the BotData.minecraftServer. is the process p from the first block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found it, it is needed to use write() newline() then flush() to send anything to the console.

My second problem was a dead reference to my process.

destroying the process doesn't work, but the stop command does.

using / is useless, \n doesn't replace newline()

Answer (score 0):

[document](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands) says commands from cmd should come with a leading `/`.
Try send `/stop` instead of `stop`.

Also mind, the line `line = r.readLine();` may never return a `null` while the process is alive(by default).

Comment: I did try that already and nothing different happened, some other stack thread talked about using somethign like "Command:>>" before the command and it did nothing either, with and without /

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, you can use pipes for this. Pipe the two programs together using named pipes, and the stdin for your java program will be the stdout for the minecraft server, and vice versa. You can send commands with the print function, and you can receive inputs by reading stdin. I don't know java, but a quick google seems to suggest that you can do this. I'm doing it right now with python, and the most nifty part is that it's language interchangeable. As long as you can access stdin and stdout, you can make a program talk to your minecraft server. The biggest problem I'm facing at this point is synchronizing an "ask" (a command that returns data) with an "answer" (the data returned). Any number of interfering server logs could occur between the two and cause interference.

Note that debugging can become very difficult because the print function of your add-on will pipe straight into the other program